# PikePdf installation failure only when using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, executable, auto-py-to-exe, pikepdf

I am trying to install use pyinstaller to turn all my scripts into an exe file. I am just using auto-py-to-exe which I believe uses pyinstaller under the hood.

However, I've come across this issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 409, in from_name
StopIteration

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pikepdf\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 352, in exec_module
  File "pikepdf\_version.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 910, in version
  File "importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 883, in distribution
  File "importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 411, in from_name
importlib_metadata.PackageNotFoundError: No package metadata was found for pikepdf

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scheduling_master.py", line 18, in <module>
    import resume_pkg
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 352, in exec_module
  File "resume_pkg.py", line 12, in <module>
    import pikepdf
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 352, in exec_module
  File "pikepdf\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
ImportError: Failed to determine version
```

This only happens **AFTER** I open the executable. Turning it into an executable has no errors. Furthermore, if I run the scripts stand-alone it has no import error and lets me run it without error.
How would I go about fixing this?
I've tried reinstalling / installing other versions.
Right now I have auto-py-to-exe as version 2.35.0 and pikepdf as version 5.4.2

Answer (score 1):

In `auto-py-to-exe` after entering the script and selecting all the options that you have checked in previous attempts, click on the "advanced" dropdown, then find the option that says `--recursive-copy-metadata` and click the `"+"` button.  Then inside of the edit box enter `pikepdf` and then click the convert button at the bottom, and that should solve your issue.

ALternatively, use pyinstaller and add the following to the CLI args.

```
--recursive-copy-metadata pikepdf
```